# what's the possible result of the following code in concurrency situation?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have seen an interview question as below:
What's the possible range of the result of the following code:

```
void ThreadProc(int& sum)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
    {
        sum += 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    thread t1(ThreadProc, std::ref(sum));
    thread t2(ThreadProc, std::ref(sum));
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    cout << sum << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The given answer is **[50,100]**.
However, I thought it should be **[2,100]**.
If given sequence as below, `sum` will be **2**.

1. thread `t1` get the cpu, and load the initial `sum=0` into cache (let's say the cached sum is `c1`, its value is `0` now).
2. thread `t2` get the cpu, and increase (49 times), and now the sum will be 49.
3. thread `t1` get the cpu, and compute `sum = c1 + 1`, now `sum` is `1`.
4. thread `t2` get the cpu, and load the `sum` (`=1`) and compute `sum + 1` and cached the result (`c1` is `2` now). Before the `c1` is written to variable `sum` by `t1`, `t2` preempt the cpu.
5. thread `t2` get the cpu, and increase (1 times) [and now the `sum` will be `x` (the value does't matter)], then `thread t2` finished.
6. thread `t1` get the cpu, and write the cached result `c1` to sum,
   now `sum` is `2`.

   **Am I right?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code causes [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939) because `sum` is modified from two different threads without any concurrency protection. This is called a *data race* in the C++ Standard.

Therefore any behaviour whatsoever is possible (including but not limited to all the cases you mention).

[Link to cppreference page about memory model](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model).

Comment: is it the same in other popular language, such as c#, Java

Comment: @ricky this answer only applies to C++.  The situation would be similar in C, and I don't know about any other languages

Comment: If you like more details, you could look into safe, regular and atomic registers. Since most modern day behaviors are atomic(are they?) in their loads and stores, the value of [2, 100] seems like a correct answer in a practical sense. Obviously the standard says its undefined behavior due to data race, and so, as per the standard it might display arbitrary values like 345, but pragmatically I don't think you'll get any value outside [2, 100]. Please correct me because I might be horribly wrong.